# Confusion about google cloud endpoints ESP and ESP v2 beta

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm a little confused about the support of cloud endpoints for cloud functions in GCP.

In the [documentation page for endpoints for cloud functions](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-functions) it states that right now there's a **beta** phase for ESP v2 and clearly explains how to configure them. From this sentence it seems to me that there's some sort of GA version of ESP for functions:

> Previous releases of Cloud Endpoints supported the use of the
>   Extensible Service Proxy (ESP) with Cloud Functions

But I can't find any documentation about ESP in specific.

I would like to understand two things:

1) when did ESP v2 enter the beta phase ? Is there an estimate time for the GA launch ?

2) Is there a GA version of cloud endpoints for cloud functions ?

Maybe someone already tried to implement this in the past and can tell me a little bit of history about ESP and ESP v2 migration, to understand if choosing this over cloud endpoints framework is worth the shoot.

Comment: Some information will be in the release notes: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/release-notes Review the repository https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/esp-v2 Migrating to ESPv2 Review https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/migrate-to-esp-v2

Comment: Use V2, all the things that are coming are on V2 version!

Comment: thank you guys, @guillaumeblaquiere the problem is that the beta state is not stable, if I've to put in production a product with some SLA I can't rely only on that :(

Comment: @Pievis, from my experience, GCP beta service = GA service without SLA. In other words, the service are very stable and reliable but not financially  backed (gmail is a google example!!). The "beta" signification isn't the same for all Cloud Provider!